# Finding probability of strictrly less than, when expectance and variance are given

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, variance, standard-deviation

A gardener grows cabagge. The weight of a ripe cabbage, $X$, is assumed to have normal distribution with the expectance $\mu = 2.4$ kg and standard weight $\sigma = 0.7$

If we pick a random cabagge, what is the probability that...

1. ... it weighs less than 1.5 kg?
2. ... weighs between 2 and 2.5 kg?
3. ... the difference in weight between two random cabbages is greater than 1 kg?

---

**(1)**

So we have $X\sim Normal(\mu,\sigma)$, and

\begin{align}\\
& P(X\le a) = \phi\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}\right) \\
& P(X\ge b) = 1-\phi\left(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right) \\
\end{align}

But what is the formula for *strictly* less than, i.e. $P(X<c)?$

Edit: Is it $P(X<c)=1-P(X\ge b)?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, if you are working with a continuous variable you have the following:
\begin{equation*}
P(X=a) = 0, \hspace{.2cm} \forall a
\end{equation*}
And
\begin{equation*}
P(X\leq a) = P(X <a) + P(X=a) = P(X<a)
\end{equation*}
So the formula is the same, for continuous variables.